# Using Oracle DataBase through WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, wcf, iis

I'm facing a strange issue while trying to connect to database to read data in my WCF JSON Web Service. Whenever I open:

```
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
 conn.ConnectionString = "";
 conn.Open();
```

then an error occurs:
[image]

This error will be shown only if you accessed it through IIS localhost, through VS 2013 LocalHost works fine. I don't get it what's the problem exactly?

I've tested it several times and it works each time in VS 2013 localhost while it'll not in IIS localhost and I'm trying to host it in IIS.

Kindly help.

Best Regards

Comment: Excuse me, am I forgetting anything further to do? I'm very surprised because it works with local host, by hosting it on IIS it not work. Please help.